# How to set the url on a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and inside one of the columns is a `HyperLinkField`.
I want to set the url to a page `Exemplu.aspx?id={}`, where `id` is the id of the element from a database.
How to set the id for every element?
In the grid I have the `id`, but when I open the page how to I do `Exemplu.aspx?id=50` for example?

Thank you for helping me.
I know that for some of you this isn't an issue.

Comment: But the id will be different based on the element that I select.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 This is an asp.net question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="UnitPrice"
            datanavigateurlfields="ProductID"
            datanavigateurlformatstring="~\details.aspx?ProductID={0}"          
            target="_blank" />
```

Comment: Yikes. God bless MVC!

Comment: @BenjaminPaul I hear you

Answer (score 0):

try the following. Add hyperlink field in column

```
<COLUMNS>     
    <ASP:HYPERLINKFIELD text="Detail" datanavigateurlfields="id" datanavigateurlformatstring="Exemplu.aspx?id={0}"></ASP:HYPERLINKFIELD>         
</COLUMNS>
```